# Running total with over clause on SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, windows, function, cumulative-sum

I use the following T-SQL sub-query to calculate running total quantity by `RefId`.

As my table has more than 2M of rows I would like to rewrite the query with using an `OVER` clause.

But I can't get the same result; when `CreationDate` is not unique for `RefId`, the result is not correct because the previous row with same date is added to the sum.

Is there a solution to get the correct result?

Sample data set:

```
CREATE TABLE Command 
(
    CreationDate SMALLDATETIME,
    RefId INT,
    Qte INT
);


INSERT INTO Command VALUES('2021-01-10', 100, 10);
INSERT INTO Command VALUES('2021-01-11', 100, 20);
INSERT INTO Command VALUES('2021-01-11', 100, 60);
INSERT INTO Command VALUES('2021-01-11', 100, 10);
INSERT INTO Command VALUES('2021-01-12', 100, 20);
INSERT INTO Command VALUES('2021-01-10', 200, 20);
INSERT INTO Command VALUES('2021-01-11', 200, 10);
INSERT INTO Command VALUES('2021-01-12', 200, 20);
INSERT INTO Command VALUES('2021-01-12', 200, 10);
```

Subquery with correct result

```
SELECT 
    c1.*,
    (SELECT SUM(c2.Qte) 
     FROM Command c2
     WHERE c1.RefId = c2.RefId
       AND c2.CreationDate < c1.CreationDate) AS RunninTotal_Qte
FROM 
    Command c1
ORDER BY 
    c1.RefId, c1.CreationDate
```

[image: Result Sub-Query]

Query rewrite with `OVER` clause; result is incorrect

```
SELECT 
    c1.*,
    SUM(c1.Qte) OVER (PARTITION BY c1.RefId ORDER BY c1.CreationDate 
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS RunningTotal_Qte
FROM 
    Command c1
ORDER BY 
    c1.RefId, c1.CreationDate
```

[image]

Comment: why do you wanna do it with `OVER`? seems like you are doing it in the simple way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way you are already doing it is more performant anyway if you must,here is how to do it using only window functions:

```
SELECT c1.*,
  SUM(c1.Qte) OVER (PARTITION BY c1.RefId ORDER BY c1.CreationDate) 
    - SUM(c1.Qte) OVER (PARTITION BY c1.RefId, c1.CreationDate ORDER BY c1.CreationDate) AS RunningTotal_Qte
FROM Command c1
ORDER BY c1.RefId, c1.CreationDate
```

Comment: Well done. Im must improve my algebra! Result is correct. But you have right when I test with the real data set performance are better with the initial sub-query. Never mind thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c1.*,
SUM(c1.Qte) OVER(PARTITION BY c1.RefId ORDER BY c1.CreationDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as RunningTotal_Qte
FROM Command c1
ORDER BY c1.RefId, c1.CreationDate
```

Comment: Thank you. But the result is not the same than the sub-query

Comment: Yes. But could you please explain why in the query with subquery in the third row you have got Qte=60 and RunningTotal=10

Comment: To clarify I want to get sub total only for the previous days. So if we are the 11th we sum Qte only for the preceding dates ie 10th . My company use this rule to calculate the rolling stock.